# Ordered subsets test

Tags: python, tuples, subset, python-itertools

I want to test if an ordered set is a subset of a bigger ordered set. I used tuples and `itertools.combinations`:

```
def subset_test(a, b):
    return a in itertools.combinations(b, len(a))
```

For instance,

```
>>> subset_test((0, 1, 2), (0, 3, 1, 4, 2))
True
>>> subset_test((0, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2, 4, 1))
False
```

It works, but is slow when I test big tuples.

Comment: @senderle, Could you suggest a better term? I want to test if A is a subset of the ordered set B.

Comment: Regarding your original code, there is no need to call `list`, you can check membership in a generator too and it will save one run through the combinations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply use an iterator to keep track of the position in B

```
>>> A = (0, 1, 2)
>>> B = (0, 3, 1, 4, 2)
>>> b_iter = iter(B)
>>> all(a in b_iter for a in A)
True
```

Comment: Oh, wow! I see why this works, but it looks like black magic. Is the behavior of `in` in this case guaranteed?

Comment: Is there anything in the standard that requires `in` to use linear iteration and to stop the moment a match is found? I can't imagine it would be done any other way, but might still be a problem for the "general case".

Comment: @MadPhysicist, of course not. `in` calls the underlying `__contains__` method. For example, for a `dict`, `in` is certainly not linear search. On the other hand it has to be a linear search for an iterator - how could it mean anything else?

Answer (score 4):

Simple way of doing this

```
>>> a = (0, 1, 2)
>>> b = (0, 3, 1, 4, 2)
>>> filter(set(a).__contains__, b) == a
True
```

For greater efficiency use `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import ifilter, imap
>>> from operator import eq
>>> all(imap(eq, ifilter(set(a).__contains__, b), a))
True
```

Comment: or `filter(functools.partial(operator.contains, a), b)` etc.

Comment: @gnibbler Would you say that it's better to do it like that or is it ok to use special methods in this case?

Comment: The special method version seems to run about twice as fast. List comprehension seems to be slowest of all.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

```
>>> A = (0, 1, 2)
>>> B = (0, 3, 1, 4, 2)
>>> b_idxs = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(B)}
>>> idxs = [b_idxs[i] for i in A]
>>> idxs == sorted(idxs)
True
```

If the list comprehension throws a `KeyError`, then obviously the answer is also `False`

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty quick, but I have a faster one in mind I hope to have down soon:

```
def is_sorted_subset(A, B):
    try:
      subset = [B.index(a) for a in A]
      return subset == sorted(subset)
    except ValueError:
      return False
```

Update: here's the faster one I promised.

```
def is_sorted_subset(A, B):
  max_idx = -1
  try:
    for val in A:
      idx = B[max_idx + 1:].index(val)
      if max(idx, max_idx) == max_idx:
        return False
      max_idx = idx
  except ValueError:
    return False
  return True
```

Comment: Note that this could become slow if `B` is huge since `list.index` is O(N)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a linear time approach (in the longest set) that doesn't require any hashing. It takes advantage of the fact that, since both sets are ordered, earlier items in the set don't need to be re-checked:

```
>>> def subset_test(a, b):
...     b = iter(b)
...     try:
...         for i in a:
...             j = b.next()
...             while j != i:
...                 j = b.next()
...     except StopIteration:
...         return False
...     return True
...
```

A few tests:

```
>>> subset_test((0, 1, 2), (0, 3, 1, 4, 2))
True
>>> subset_test((0, 2, 1), (0, 3, 1, 4, 2))
False
>>> subset_test((0, 1, 5), (0, 3, 1, 4, 2))
False
>>> subset_test((0, 1, 4), (0, 3, 1, 4, 2))
True
```

I'm pretty sure this is right -- let me know if you see any problems.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
>>> a = (0, 1, 2)
>>> b = (0, 3, 1, 4, 2)
>>> set(a).issubset(set(b))
True
```

In this example a and b have ordered and unique elements and it checks if a is subset of b. Is this you want?

EDIT:

According to @Marcos da Silva Sampaio: "I want to test if A is a subset of the ordered set B."

It wouldn't be the case of:

```
>>> a = (2, 0, 1)
>>> b = (0, 3, 1, 4, 2)
>>> set(b).issuperset(a)
True
```

In this case the order of a doesn't matters.

Comment: The elements of `a` may not be ordered correctly eg. `(2, 1, 0)` in `(0, 3, 1, 4, 2)`