# Finding list elements in order in another list, but not consecutively? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to figure out a cleaner (Pythonic) way to tell whether elements in one list exist in another list, in order but not consecutively. For example, I might have the following lists:

```
list1 = ["I", "her"]
list2 = ["I", "hate", "her", "sometimes"]
list3 = ["her", "hat", "I", "found"]
```

I want to return `True` when comparing list1 to list2, because "I" and "her" exist in list2 in that order, although not consecutively. `False` would be returned when comparing list1 to list3, because "her" and "I" do not appear in the correct order.

I could write a series of loops and if statements to achieve this, but I was wondering if there was a simpler, built-in way to do it. I have tried using the all() function:

```
all(i in list2 for i in list1)
```

This works to find whether all the elements in list1 exist in list2, but does not account for ordering. I've also tried using join:

```
" ".join(str(i) for i in list1) in list2
```

This will only return `True` if the elements from list1 are consecutive in list2.

Any ideas on a simpler way to do this?

Comment: This should require, at most, a single loop.

Comment: What should be the result of comparing `list1` to itself?

Comment: Your example lists are not valid Python (or, at best, the code is incomplete).

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/34599113/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Not sure closed questions are the *best* references...

Comment: @ScottHunter  why not? The answers posted there are quite valid and recognized as such by the community.

Comment: That being said, my absolute favorite is https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820887/2988730. It's about as concise and efficient as you can get.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not quite, I do know how to do what I am aiming for using normal loops. I was just wondering if there was a specific Python function to do this, since Python has so much built-in functionality for manipulating lists.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The second link you included is the one! Sorry I didn't see it.

Comment: Should I delete this thread? I apologize for posting a repeat, I'm a bit new.

Comment: @A.S. delete is fine. Mark as duplicate too

Answer (score -1):

Just use the intersection operator for sets:

```
result = bool(set(list1) & set(list2))
```

If you want to count only ordered pairs, use zip.

```
result = any([el1 == el2 for el1, el2 in zip (list1, list2)])
```

Comment: This one doesn't quite work, since it returns True regardless of the ordering of the elements in the second list. For example, it would return True when comparing list1 and list3 also, when it should return False.

Comment: try the second solution I posted for ordered pairs