# Simple method to find 0,0,1 in that order, within a given List

Tags: python, python-3.x, subsequence

I am trying to write a simple  function to find if 0,0,1 occurs in a list, in that order.
It should return `True` or `False`.

The list can contain any number of numbers.
For the function `ZeroZeroOne` examples would be as follows:

```
>> ZeroZeroOne( [0,0,1] )
>> True

>> ZeroZeroOne( [1,0,0] )
>> False

# there are 2s in between but the following does have 0,0,1 occurring and in correct order 
>> ZeroZeroOne( [0,2,2,2,2,0,1] )
>> True
```

I have this function:

```
def ZeroZeroOne(nums):
      
    FoundIt = False

    #quick return if defo not possible
    if (nums.count(0) < 2) and (nums.count(1) == 0):
        return FoundIt

    n = len(nums)
    for x in range(n-2):
        if nums[x] == 0:
            for i,z in enumerate(nums[(x+1):]):
                if z==0 and z!=1:
                    for j,q in enumerate(nums[(i+1):]):
                        if q==1 and q!=0:
                            FoundIt=True

    return FoundIt
```

Why does the function return True for this list `[0, 1, 0, 2, 1]`?

Moreover....
This function seems overly-complex for a seemingly simple problem.

- Is there a correct approach to this problem in Python - a *canonical* or *Pythonic* approach?
- Or is ones approach simply opinion-based?

Comment: Why dont you iterate thru and slice 3 items to check if they are 0,0,1?

Comment: this looks like more appropriate for [codereview.se]. In any case - you can short circuit

Comment: What about `[0, 1, 0, 2, 1]`, would that be `True` or `False`?

Comment: @L3viathan that would be False - at some range in the list there has to be 0,...0 ....1 but 1,0,0  or 0,1,0 fail

Comment: @whytheq not according to your function. Also: Why is it False?

Comment: @L3viathan - ok - so I guess I can make the question more specific now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single loop - O(n) time complexity. Since it is for this specific case. Try the code below.

```
def ZeroZeroOne(nums):
    found_pattern = []
    for num in nums:
        if num == 1:
            found_pattern.append(1)
            if len(found_pattern) == 3:
                return True
            else:
                found_pattern = []
        elif num == 0 and len(found_pattern) < 2:
            found_pattern.append(0)
    return False


print(ZeroZeroOne([0, 0, 1]))
print(ZeroZeroOne([0, 1, 0, 2, 1]))
print(ZeroZeroOne([0, 2, 0, 1]))
print(ZeroZeroOne([0, 0, 0, 1]))
print(ZeroZeroOne([0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1]))
```

But I think you can generalize this as well if required. Probably you need to look in to how **grep** works and modify it for your use case if you want a generic approach.

Comment: (upped) to avoid my nested looping to do as O(n) is very cool. I actually love this answer - as a beginner in Python it's very easy to understand but also quick.

Answer (score 2):

You can trivially modify the ordered subsequence test from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820887/2988730) for an elegant solution:

```
def ZeroZeroOne(arr):
    test = iter(a for a in arr if a in (0, 1))
    return all(z in test for z in (0, 0, 1))
```

**I realize now that you don't want to accept 0, 1 0, 1.**

---

You can use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to check for a match:

```
def ZeroZeroOne(arr):
    e = itertools.tee((a for a in arr if a in (0, 1)), 3)
    # move second iterator forward one
    next(e[1])
    # move third iterator forward two
    next(e[2])
    next(e[2])
    return (0, 0, 1) in zip(*e)
```

The nice thing about using `tee` in this case is that it effectively maintains a rolling buffer of the last three elements for you. You don't need to make a new slice or loop over indices it anything like that.

---

Just for fun, here's a more general solution in pure python. It accepts any iterable for `arr` and `template`:

```
def contains_template(arr, template):
    template = tuple(template)
    unique = set(template)
    filtered = (a for a in arr if a in unique)
    e = itertools.tee(filtered, len(template))
    for n, it in enumerate(e):
        for _ in range(n):
            next(it)
    return template in zip(*e)
```

---

While `itertools.tee` is a nice way to maintain a rolling buffer, you can implement the same thing using a list (or more efficiently, `collections.deque`):

```
def contains_template(arr, template):
    template = list(template)
    unique = set(template)
    filtered = (a for a in arr if a in unique)
    buffer = [next(filtered) for _ in range(len(template) - 1)]
    buffer.insert(0, None)
    for e in filtered:
        buffer.pop(0)
        buffer.append(e)
        if template == buffer:
            return True
    return False
```

---

Finally, here is the really simple solution, without a rolling buffer:

```
def contains_template(arr, template):
    template = list(template)
    n = len(template)
    unique = set(template)
    filtered = [a for a in arr if a in unique]
    return any(filtered[i:i + n] == template for i in range(len(filtered) - n))
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. I was wondering if we replace `a in (0, 1)` with `a in {0, 1}` would it be more efficient?

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz. For a bigger number of elements, probably. For just two integers it's more efficient to just check both.

Comment: the updated solution is brilliant! I also learned something new: `itertools.tee`.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz. Glad you like it. Tee is a bit arcane because it's rarely useful.

Comment: (For some reason I can't mention you in a comment). Yeah, but it's good to know. I haven't seen it in production code but would be very useful in such a scenario.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz. You don't need to mention the post author. I will get notified of any comments or edits to my answer automatically.

Comment: (upped) thanks for this answer. can the just for fun solution be adapted to not use `itertools.tee` ... I am beginning my python journey so the simpler the better!

Comment: @whytheq. Let me know if the update works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a recursive function :

```py
def check(seq, liste, i=0, j=0):
    if i >= len(seq):
        return True
    if j >= len(liste):
        return False
    if seq[i] == liste[j]:
        return check(seq, liste, i + 1, j + 1)
    elif liste[j] in seq:
        # look for the last index you can restart from
        for k in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
            if seq[k] == liste[j]:
                if seq[:k] == seq[i - k:i]:
                    ind = k
                    break
        else:
            ind = 0
        return check(seq, liste, ind, j + (not i))
    else:
        return check(seq, liste, i, j + 1)



# seq = [0,0,1] for ZeroZeroOne
print(check([0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]))  # True
print(check([0, 0, 1], [0, 200, 0, 0, 101, 1]))  # True
print(check([0, 2, 2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 4, 2, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1]))  # True
print(check([0, 2, 2, 0, 1], [0, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1]))  # False
```

Comment: your algorithm looks good. But check this case `print(check([0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]))`

Comment: (upped) thanks for the extra functionality of generalizing the search term

Comment: actually it's not that generalized for now because `print(check([0,2,0,1],[0,2,4,2,0,3,1]))` returns true, working on a fix

Comment: Ok so it's a bit more complicated but it should work for all cases now !

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want :)

```
def ZeroZeroOne(arr):
    dropped = [x for x in arr if x==0 or x==1]
    slices = [dropped[i:i+3] for i in range(len(dropped)-2)]
    if [0,0,1] in slices: return True
    else: return False
```

Comment: What if the pair is found the very first time? Do we need to make all the pairs beforehand?

Comment: Yea, you could slice through the options and break as soon as you find a match, makes the code longer, but would be faster. As nothing was specified about parsing a lot of data this way, I assumed it would be fine to have the nicer looking function :)

Comment: you can do `return any([dropped[i:i+3] for i in range(len(dropped)-2)])` This will ensure it breaks the loop as soon as the first one is found. It will also ensure it returns False if all of them fail

Comment: also first check if `arr` is less than 3. Then you don't have to do anything. just return `False`

Comment: Oh cool! Did not know that! Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Also do this `dropped = [x for x in arr if x in (0,1)]`

Comment: Use this ...`return any([dropped[i:i+3]==[0,0,1] for i in range(len(dropped)-2)])`

Answer (score 1):

```
def ZeroZeroOne(nums):
    filtered_nums = [x for x in nums if x in [0,1]]
    return '*'.join([str(x) for x in [0,0,1]) in '*'.join([str(x) for x in filtered_nums])
```

Comment: Try this with the list `[20, 0, 13]` for example.

Comment: oh ok. won't work for that case. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Added a temporary character